# C# web service and dll library

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, dllimport

I have this doubt ..

I have a `C++` library dll and I am writing in my `c#` web service.
I should call my web service a method of this dll.
for example using:

```
[DllImport ("mydll.dll")]
....
```

but how the type mappings? For example, If That library dll function pointers?

Import and calls the dll adds a overead significant as regards the perdformance?

it may be desirable from the point of view of performance write the web service in `C++`?
using `c#` I think it's much faster to implement.

Comment: ?? what is the question??

Comment: but how the type mappings? For example, If That library dll function pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the marshalling process and specifically about marshalling function pointers? The CLR [marshals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx) most native types into their managed equivalents. A more fine grained control of the marshalling process can be achieved using the `MarshalAs` attribute. As far as function pointers are concerned,  you can use [GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) to get managed delegates for your native function pointers. [Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/14/181932.aspx) an example of this.

You also asked about performance considerations related to P/Invoke. There is obviously some overhead when using P/Invoke. Here's what [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx) says about it.

> PInvoke has an overhead of between 10 and 30 x86 instructions per call. In addition to this fixed cost, marshaling creates additional overhead. There is no marshaling cost between blittable types that have the same representation in managed and unmanaged code. For example, there is no cost to translate between int and Int32.
>   For better performance, have fewer PInvoke calls that marshal as much data as possible, instead of more calls that marshal less data per call.

To wrap up, use P/Invoke if there is no managed equivalent of the DLL you are calling into. To avoid the performance hit of P/Invoke, it might be a good idea to just implement your DLL in managed code. There could of course be other performance considerations which led you to implement it as a native DLL though. You just need to weight the pros and cons and do what seems right.